# How to reduce the file size on JPEG images in batch (/Mac)?

Tags: command-line, jpeg, batch-processing

I have a list of .JPG files on a Mac. I want to export them to a format taking less than 500 kilobytes per image.
I know how to do that using the Preview application one image at a time; but I want to be able to do the same in batch, meaning on several files at once. Is there a command line way to do it so I could write a script and run it in the terminal?
Or some other way that I could use?

Comment: What is the desired output format that would take less space that you want to use? In ImageMagick, you can use the mogrify command to process a whole folder of images in one command line. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify. If the output is also JPG, then you can just change the -quality value in the command line. You can install ImageMagick using Homebrew or MacPorts or from an ImageMagick binary. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is an example from the command line using [convert](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) (`brew info imagemagick`) converting all `*.jpg` images in one directory to `.png`:

```
$ for i in *.jpg; do
convert "$i" "${i%.jpg}.png"
done
```

To test before (dry-run) you could use `echo` instead of the `<command>`:

```
$ for i in *.jpg; do
echo "$i" "${i%.jpg}.png"
done
```

This will search for files within the directory having the extension `.jpg` then execute the command `convert` passing as arguments the file name `$i` and then using as an output the same file name removing the extension and adding the new one `.png`, this is done using:

```
"${i%.jpg}.png"
```

The use of double quotes `"` is for the case file could contain spaces, check this for more details: [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

For example, to just change the quality of the file you could use:

```
convert "$i" -quality 80% "${i%.jpg}-new.jpg"
```

Or if no need to keep the original:

```
mogrify -quality 80% *.jpg
```

> The main difference is that ‘convert‘ tends to be for working on individual images, whereas ‘mogrify‘ is for batch processing multiple files.

Answer (score 14):

Install [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/).  (Really.. it's lightweight and amazing)  It's nice to install using [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/imagemagick). Then...

1. Open terminal.
2. `cd [FilepathWithImages] && mogrify -define jpeg:extent=60kb -resize 400  *.JPG`
3. Wait until the process is complete (may take a few minutes if you have many images)
4. To check file sizes, try `du -sh *` to see the size of each file in the directory you're in.

**NOTE: `*.JPG` must be uppercase for it to work**

How this works:
`cd [yourfilepath]` will naviage to the directory you want to be in
`&&` is used for chaining commands
`mogrify` is used when you want to keep the same filename
`-define jpeg:extent=60kb` sets the maximum filesize to 60kb
`-resize 400` will set the width
`*.JPG` is for all files in the directory you're in.

There are many additional commands you can use with imagemagick convert and mogrify.  After installing it, you can use `man mogrify` to see the commands you can chain to it.

According to [the docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#extent), "Restrict the maximum JPEG file size, for example `-define jpeg:extent=400KB`. The JPEG encoder will search for the highest compression quality level that results in an output file that does not exceed the value. The `-quality` option also will be respected starting with version 6.9.2-5. Between 6.9.1-0 and 6.9.2-4, add `-quality 100` in order for the `jpeg:extent` to work properly. Prior to 6.9.1-0, the `-quality` setting was ignored."

Answer (score 4):

Install ImageMagick from Homebrew or MacPorts or from https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx. Then use mogrify to process all files in a folder using -define jpeg:extent=500KB saving to JPG.

I have two files in folder test1 on my desktop. Processing will put them into folder test2 on my desktop

```
Before Processing:

mandril.tif 3.22428MB (3.2 MB)
zelda.png 726153B (726 KB)

cd
cd desktop/test1
mogrify -path ../test2 -format jpg -define jpeg:extent=500KB *

After Processing:

mandril.jpg 358570B (359 KB)
zelda.jpg 461810B (462 KB)
```

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify

The * at the end means to process all files in the folder. If you want to restrict to only jpg then change it to *.jpg. The -format means you intend the output to be jpg.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER: BE CAREFUL BECAUSE THE FOLLOWING SOLUTION IS A "DESTRUCTIVE" COMMAND, FILES ARE REPLACED WITH LOWER QUALITY DIRECTLY**

Now that you have read my disclaimer, I would recommend to get [cwebp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/cwebp) that you can download [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download).

You will also need parallel `sudo apt-get install -y parallel` and then I coined the following script:

```sh
parallel cwebp {} -resize 0 640 -m 6 -sns 100 -q 80 -preset photo -segments 4 -f 100  -o {} ::: *.jpg && /
find -name "*.jpg" | parallel 'f="{}" ; mv -- {} ${f:0:-3}webp'
```

640 is the resulting file height in pixels and 0 before means that the width will adapt to the ratio between width and height.
I reduced quality to 80% (-q 80), you will not notice much difference.

The second line find all the files that have been converted but still have the wrong extension file (.jpg), so it removes the last 3 characters (jpg) and add webp instead.

I went from 5 Mb to about 50k per file (.jpg images were 4000x4000 pixels) , just saved 20 Gb of storage. I hope you enjoy it !

If you don't want to bother with webp format you can use the following instead (you will need to install [imageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) perhaps):

```sh
parallel convert {} -resize x640 -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip -quality 85 \
-interlace JPEG -colorspace RGB -define jpeg:dct-method=float {} ::: *.jpg
```